# Quarto RevealJs video autoplay

Tags: html5-video, reveal.js, quarto

I have a video in a slide:

```
![](video/filename.mp4)
```

and I have set YAML option for global autoplay:

```
format: 
  revealjs:
    auto-play-media: true
```

but on page the video is not autoplaying.

I have searched and most results relate to RevealJs only rather than Quarto and suggest a raw HTML format (e.g. below) which when I try in Quarto is not recognised:

```
<video data-autoplay src="http://file.mp4"></video>
```

Please help.  P.S. I understand the first slide may not autoplay but this is a slide in middle of deck.

I am trying to switch from Powerpoint to Quarto.

Comment: Using `<video data-autoplay src="test_vid.mp4"></video>` works in my case without even using `auto-play-media: true`. Don't know why it isn't working for you. Do you get any error message?

Comment: For others that experience similar issues, please note that failure to auto-play may be due to a browser setting : check and make sure, that your browser doesn't prevent auto-play!